# How to files source address to fix GitHub page files 404

Tags: github, github-pages

**- Introduction**

I have a Vue.js SPA project, and I got 404 for my all files after a new published GitHub page.

[=> 404 files page Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFbgT.png)

---

**- Found**

I found out the source address is wrong.

**Wrong** => https://sandra-kao.github.io/js/

**Correct** =>https://sandra-kao.github.io/<project-name>/js/app.9d5a7abd.js

---

**- Problem**

My problem is, how to change the root url

from "https://sandra-kao.github.io/"

to "https://sandra-kao.github.io/*always-code*"

---

I tried this from [Vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#platform-guides)

```
module.exports = 
{
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/my-project/'
    : '/'
}
```

Comment: After tried sevrl times, I occurent an error when i build project in GitHub Action.

`The deploy step encountered an error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128 ❌`

Answer (score 0):

I solving this by the following steps:

1. Config webpack. (To do this in [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables))
2. Set up [environment for .evn](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)
3. Set your production config in [webpack(vue.config.js)](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#github-pages)
4. Republish your page

and problem solved.